# return 0 mysqli_affected_rows and mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, function, mysqli

i use your function db_connect and db_query(), but i have a question: how i use mysqli_insert_id() and mysqli_affected_rows(), because the value return 0.

```
function db_connect(){
    static $connection;
        require_once __DIR__ . '/cfconfig.php'; 
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    $connection->set_charset('utf8');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    return $connection;
}

function db_query($query) {
    $connection =  db_connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    return $result;
}
```

example:

```
db_query("INSERT INTO  ....
```

after this:

```
$afectrows = mysqli_affected_rows(db_connect());
$insertid = mysqli_insert_id(db_connect());
```

The value return 0

Comment: Was a record successfully inserted?  Did it include an auto-incrementing ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your function that it creating the new connection every time it is called, despite some cargo cult static variable hanging around.

To make it work you have to make your connection real static

```
function db_connect(){
    static $connection;
    if (!$connection) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/cfconfig.php'; 
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        $connection->set_charset('utf8');
    }
    return $connection;
}
```

now you can get your insert id all right

```
$id = db_connect()->insert_id;
```